# Is there any possibilities to set proxy settings through program for android emulator

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, android-emulator, appium

I knew there will be some possibilities to set proxy, and ssl and port number through program in webdriver. Is there any similar possibilities in appium(emulator)? Please do let me know If you have any solution on this.

Answer (score 2):

Appium doesn't support proxies at this stage. Check this [issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4968) out.